# Convert the input (type="time") to Time instead of String

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am getting time input in the format of string. I need to convert it to datetime type in order to send it to the API. How can I convert a string to datetime?

```
<input
 placeholder="enter time"
 type="time"
 onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Need to convert Time to datetime datatype.

Comment: What do you mean by `datetime` datatype? If you are using any framework, backend, library etc. please also add to your tags.

Comment: What do you mean by "datetime type"? Are you talking about a DateTime object in PHP? Well then _create_ one, from the given string value, in your PHP code.

Comment: If I create a Date object, I get an object. Is there any time or datetime datatype in JS?

Comment: Pass a string to the API and convert it to the appropriate type there.

Answer (score 0):

change your input type to :

```
type="datetime"
```

Comment: I need to get time as well

Comment: it is worked???

Comment: use type="datetime"

Comment: its worked now ???

Comment: datetime still gives me a string

Comment: so you need object type?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your time in a new [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) type like :

```
<input
 placeholder="enter time"
 type="time"
 onChange={setTime(this)}
/>

function setTime(time) {
 const today = new Date();
 console.log(new Date(today.toDateString() + ' ' + time.value));
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hL3aqp2e/8/)